# Launch a view with textField with an init number of 0.00

Tags: ios, text, numbers, uitextfield, init

I am trying to build an app that manage some decimal values (as practice as I am beginner) in some textFields.
I want the app to launch with those numbers being 0.00 (no currency, just numbers).
I do not know if I have to handle that inside an overridden "init" method.

Also, is it possible to handle those same textFields to go back to 0.00 if the user delete is current number and just leaves it empty.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Inside `viewDidAppear`, you'll want to set the text of the `UITextField`s --

```
[self textFieldName] setText:@"0.00"];
```

2) Your controller should adhere to `UITextFieldDelegate` and it should I would implement it something like the following --

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  
{
    NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

3) To reset the text field, I would implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` method as follows --

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([[textField text] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [textField setText:@"0.00"];
    }
}
```

Post a comment if you have a further questions.  Good luck.

Comment: I cannot vote up for your answer but thank you!  It is working for now!

Comment: "NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];" is that a way to programmatically say: "You only can display numbers and a dot and leave all other alphabetic key out"?

Comment: what is the newLength objet used for?  I dont see it in my code and Xcode is telling me it is not in use.

Comment: Sorry, newLength was used for something else that I was using this same code for.  It was used to determine if the length of the textField's string was too long.  And yes, that's what the characterSet var does.

Comment: I've removed the newLength var.

Answer (score 0):

There are perhaps multiple ways to do this. A straightforward way is to set the `textField` value to zero in a `viewDidLoad`. Let's assume that you have nib file and have already connected your UITextField to the outlet in the nib.

So you have something like:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

And then in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.textField.text = @"0.00";
}
```

For when the user deletes the value you need to make your `viewController` the delegate for the UITextField and then implement the textFieldDidEndEditing method.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   // Check to see if the value is empty
   if ([self.textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
   {
       self.textField.text = @"0.00";
   }
}
```

Comment: Same here, can't vote up for your answer but really appreciate the time you took to help me!  Yes, all connexion were made earlier and my @property was also created.  The IF statement is just basic... I don't how I didn't think of that by myself!

Comment: Yes, I have the textFieldDidEndEditing: because in a previous search on this website, I had to find a way to display the textField hidden by the keyboard.  I completed the code and works like a charm!